# Maven generate sources from another maven project

Tags: java, maven

In my project I have a source code generator that relies on a lot of java code to build a java source that is then stored as a string. Normally I would write the string to a .java file, but I've recently begun switching my project to Maven, and I am looking for a way to have the src file be part of the target folder so it can be used as a dependency for another maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Maven as build tool has conventions for directory layouts in the module (like `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, you've probably seen this stuff already).
All the compiled classes are put into a folder called `target` during the compile phase.
Later on, during the `package` phase the jar is created inside this `target` folder.

Now, for generated sources, there is also a kind of convention, although probably less known:

If you generate sources you should place them into:

```
target/generated-sources
```

When you do this, your IDEs (IntelliJ at least) will use them as a source files.

A process of source generation in maven is usually triggered from maven plugins attached to one of the early phases. Then, when it comes to the `package` phase these sources will be added into the jar, just like any other .class file compiled as a binary source.